# Is it "en ligne", "sur l'Internet" or "sur Internet"?

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, prépositions

I have seen many different phrases that all seem to mean online in English. Is there a distinction or canonical way of saying it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In French, you can use either "en ligne" or "sur Internet" to indicate that something is "online" or "on the internet." Both are correct and commonly used phrases. However, it is more common to use "en ligne" when referring to a specific website or service that is available online, while "sur Internet" is used to refer to the internet as a whole.

So, depending on the context of your sentence, you can use either "en ligne" or "sur Internet" to convey the meaning of "online" or "on the internet."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This clarifies, thank you! From your answer I am assuming that sur Internet is more correct that sure l'Internet. Is this correct? I also don't have enough rep to upvote this great answer yet, I'll do it as soon as I can.